# How create step lad in k6 for websocket

Tags: performance, websocket, k6

I try to generate step load for performance test on k6 for websocket.
regular settings like

```
export let options = {
    stages: [
        {
            "duration": "0m30s",
            "target": 10
        },
        {
            "duration": "0m30s",
            "target": 10
        },
        {
            "duration": "0m30s",
            "target": 0
        }
    ],

};
```

doesn't work for k6. I tried `--vus 10 --i 10`
but it just go through scenario 10 times and sleep till the end of 10 minutes.

Than I tried `k6 run --vus 5 --stage 3m:10,5m:10,10m:35,1m30s:0` but result is almost the same. How create active load with step pattern for websocket testing? to connect every time after flow is done?

Test flow:

```
import ws from "k6/ws";
import { check } from "k6";

export default function() {
  const url = "ws://URL:8000/";
  const params = { tags: { my_tag: "hello" } };

  const response = ws.connect(url, params, function(socket) {
    socket.on("open", function open() {
      console.log("connected");
      socket.send(Date.now());


   var url = "ws://URL:8000/";
   var response = ws.connect(url, null, function(socket) {
    socket.on('open', function() {
      socket.send('Hello');
      socket.send('How are you?');
    });



    socket.on("close", () => console.log("disconnected"));

    socket.on("error", (e) => {
      if (e.error() != "websocket: close sent") {
        console.log("An unexpected error occured: ", e.error());
      }
    });

  check(response, { "status is 101": r => r && r.status === 101 });
})
})
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/protocols/websockets) `ws.connect` blocks until the connection is closed either by calling `socket.close()` or the server closing the connection on the other end (or due to an error while doing something else).

So if you want to just send the 2 messages there you should call `socket.close()`. You can also close after receiving something on the other side using by using

```js
socket.on("message", function(msg) {
 console.log("got: "+ msg);
 socket.close();
}
```

But if you don't need to reconnect but instead want to just send more messages you should probably use a [timer](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/protocols/websockets):

```js
      socket.setInterval(function() {
        socket.send('Hello');
        socket.send('How are you?');
      }, 1500);
```

will send messages each 1.5s

I don't know why you open another websocket connection inside the other, but that might be a mistake on your part and is likely going to make the code hard to read if you don't use a different variable name from `socket`

Comment: I open new socket as new user connection. I need to emulate load for it. Should I add variable for this case?

Comment: I suppose you mean the inner websocket? 
You are not required but instead of using just `socket` I would recommend using `outerSocket` and `innerSocket` in order for it to be more understandable in the script

Comment: Like 
```
const outerResponse = ws.connect(url, params, function(outerSocket) {
/// do somethign with outerSocket
  const innerResponse = ws.connect(url, params, function(innerSocket) {
  // here you can use both innerSocket and outerSocket and it will be understandable
  })
  // use outerSocket
})
```

You can of course use some other name that has more meaning in your and the script context

Comment: You were right. I opened soket 2 times. Removed 1st and now works as expected with stages

Answer (score 0):

I wasted lots of time trying it with the K6 but it seems not supported till today, k6 does not support socket.io testing, check the links attached.

https://github.com/grafana/k6/issues/667

You can go for artillery, as suggested in the official socket.io docs
https://socket.io/docs/v4/load-testing/